# Download image from url if image exists

Tags: php

I have this url `www.example.com/1.png`. I want to run a loop, like so:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
$url = 'www.example.com/'.$i.'.png';
}
```

Now i have 10x urls. Lets say 7 out of 10 urls are images, and the other 3 are not available. I want to download image from each o urls, and if the url doesnt exists then it wouldnt download anything.

Heres the same thing but explained more basicly i think:

```
www.example.com/1.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/2.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/3.png --- url doesnt exist, so i dont download anything
www.example.com/4.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/5.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/6.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/7.png --- url doesnt exist, so i dont download anything
www.example.com/8.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/9.png --- url exists, so i download the image and save it in my folder.
www.example.com/10.png  --- url doesnt exist, so i dont download anything
```

Sorry for bad english, any suggestions how i can solve this problem?

Comment: where is the problem? WHat have you tried? if you don't know the function to save files you can use file_get_content() and file_put_content(), look for them in the php manual

Comment: thanks ill check `file_get_content() and file_put_content()`

Comment: Just try to download the URL. If you get an image, yay, else nay.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the images with `file_get_contents()` would generate a `$http_response_header` variable, which contains the HTTP response headers which you can check. See [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can check headers for 404 error.

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    //Does not exist
}
else
{
    //Exists, so put download code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could have done is queued them all up in one multi curl request and then filter out the ones that don't return back a value < 399. That way you could have curl requested them all at once instead of one at a time. Also set a time out for the amount of time this operation should take, say 5 seconds.